# excel year function combining formulas

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I have column 1 containing dates formated in **mm/dd/yyyy.** I want to use the **=YEAR** function to make it only show the years in column 2 (I cannot use the format cell method to do this I have to use the **YEAR** function.)However I want it to keep the blank cells in column 1 blank in column 2 by using the IF(ISBLANK function.

How do I combine the **=YEAR** and **=IF(ISBLANK** functions together without getting an error message?

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A1),"",YEAR(A1))
```

Assuming that the first date is in A1.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something you can try, and this type of question belongs on [SuperUser.com](https://superuser.com/)

```
=IF(LEN(A1)=0,YEAR(A1),"")
```